# What is the difference between error handlers and the ErrorHandlerMiddleware in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I know these questions aren't popular but I tried to ask on the CakePHP slack and got no response. I wanted to add the `Crud` CakePHP plugin to a project of mine. In order to handle errors the plugin may use a custom error handler:

```
//Crud ErrorHandler registration - simplified
(new ErrorHandler($exceptionRenderer))->register();
```

The error handler will however only be registered depending on the following check:

```
$appClass = Configure::read('App.namespace') . '\Application';

// If `App\Application` class exists it means Cake 3.3's PSR7 middleware
// implementation is used and it's too late to register new error handler.
if (!class_exists($appClass, false)) {
    $this->registerExceptionHandler();
}
```

When asked about the reasoning behind this check a `Crud` github repo member told me:

> That's because middleware queue cannot be accessed from the ApiListener to setup the custom exception renderer. [...] You aren't supposed to register the error handler yourself. The error handler middleware handles that. You are bound to have problems by doing so.

Now I cannot quite figure out what the relationship between error handlers and the `ErrorHandlerMiddleware` is. In regards to the middleware the [docs state](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html) the following:

> Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware traps exceptions from the wrapped middleware and renders an error page using the [Error & Exception Handling](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html) Exception handler

The first part of this description seems to imply that the `ErrorHandlerMiddleware`catches exceptions only from other middleware. From what I understand however the whole app is wrapped by them. The second part of the description states that the middleware uses an Exception handler to display errors. However looking through the [source](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php) of the middleware I see no reference to an *error handler*, but an *exception renderer* which is something else. The only error handling done seems to be a simple try/catch statement which renders the exception using the renderer. This seems like a mistake in the docs to me as no handler instance is actually being used.

Lastly the middleware description above points to a doc page which states:

> You can create an error handler out of any callback type. For example you could use a class called `AppError` to handle your errors. By extending the `BaseErrorHandler` you can supply custom logic for handling errors. An example would be:

```
// In config/bootstrap.php
use App\Error\AppError;
$errorHandler = new AppError(); 
$errorHandler->register();
```

But this gets me back to the start where the `Crud` github team member told me not to do this.

**Questions:**

1. What is the relationship between `ErrorHandlerMiddleware` and a
   custom error handler?
2. What happens if I register multiple error handlers - do they override?
3. What happens if my app uses the `ErrorHandlerMiddleware` but it also registers a custom error handler? Which catches what (for example exception in middleware vs exception in controller)?

Comment: The global handler and the middleware handler exist simultaneously for historical / backwards compatibility reasons, check **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/9931** and **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/11323**.

Comment: @ndm - Where does cake make the distinction of whether to use the older ErrorHandler vs the middleware? I couldn't find any invocations of ErrorHandler

Comment: @mederomuraliev The `ErrorHandler` is by default registered [**in the applications bootstrap file**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.6.2/config/bootstrap.php#L117), it will catch all errors and exceptions that are not being handled by the application, or by the error handler middleware.